# Failed to initialize ConcordionRunner

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, concordion

I use concordion to create testcases. if i run the test Class i get an Error "initializationError"  Failed to initialize ConcordionRunner.
I have no idea what that means and where is the problem.
can you guys help me to find my Problem?

I use a maven project and the pom.xml file looks like this:

```
<groupId>com.orsted.azure.test</groupId>
<artifactId>automation</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>automation</name>
<!-- <url>http://maven.apache.org</url> -->

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.concordion</groupId>
        <artifactId>concordion</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xom</groupId>
        <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1d2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ognl</groupId>
        <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And my class under src/test/java:

```
import org.concordion.integration.junit4.ConcordionRunner;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(ConcordionRunner.class)
public class ConcordianFixture {

    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Hola munda de locos!!";
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved that issue. The problem was in the name of class and html. That should have the same name but the class name should have "Fixture" as suffix.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that issue. The problem was in the name of class and html. That should have the same name but the class name should have "Fixture" as suffix.

Comment: The name of the fixture class and the specification share the same base name. The fixture has an optional suffix of “Fixture” or “Test” - for example, the fixture for the “SplittingNames.md” specification could be named “SplittingNames.java”, “SplittingNamesFixture.java” or “SplittingNamesTest.java”. See http://concordion.org/coding/java/markdown/#locating-the-specification.